# Cannot get large centered text vertically aligned with flushed text

Tags: vertical-alignment

I cannot get the name to vertically align with the text on the left or the right. Using a table seems better but its still off.

Just to clarify below are my two attempts to vertically align the name with the contact info on both sides.

The first way is using a new command i created

The second uses a table

[image: Sample]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=cyan]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\def\name{John Doe}
\def\email{john.doe@gmail.com}
\def\phone{(123) 456-7890}

\def\address{123 Main St}
\def\city{Toronto}
\def\province{ON}
\def\country{Canada}
\def\postalCode{M5Y\thinspace4Z7}


\newcommand{\rTitle}{
    \noindent
    \centerline{\Huge \textsc \name} \\
    \href{mailto:\email}{\nolinkurl{\email}} \hfill \address \\
    \texttt{\phone} \hfill \city, \province \space \postalCode \\
}

\begin{document}
    \rTitle

\noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l >{\centering}X r}
    \href{mailto:\email}{\nolinkurl{\email}} & \Huge \textsc \name & \address \\
    \texttt{\phone} && \city, \province \space \postalCode \\
  \end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Could you explain what you want it to look like? What exactly should align with what?

Comment: updated Hope its more clear now

Comment: If you are asking why the two examples aren't aligned then try to set `\tabcolsep=0pt` before the tabularx environment. BTW. The \\ after `\centerline` and after `\postalCode` are badly placed and cause the warning about underfull hbox. Remove them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use three (vertically centered) side-by-side `minipage`s:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=cyan]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\def\name{John Doe}
\def\email{john.doe@gmail.com}
\def\phone{(123) 456-7890}

\def\address{123 Main St}
\def\city{Toronto}
\def\province{ON}
\def\country{Canada}
\def\postalCode{M5Y\thinspace4Z7}


\newcommand{\rTitle}{%
    \par\noindent
    \begin{minipage}{.333\textwidth}
    \href{mailto:\email}{\nolinkurl{\email}}\par
    \texttt{\phone}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.333\textwidth}
    \centering\Huge\textsc{\name}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.333\textwidth}
     \raggedleft
     \address\par
     \city, \province \space \postalCode
    \end{minipage}\par%
}

\begin{document}

    \rTitle

\end{document}
```

Beware of spurious blan spaces in your code.

Answer (score 2):

This simple aligment can be done by simple tools without `tabularx`:

```
\centerline{\href{mailto:\email}{\nolinkurl{\email}} \hfill \address}
\centerline{\rlap{\texttt{\phone}}\hfill 
            \smash{\Huge \textsc \name}\hfill
            \llap{\province \space \postalCode}}
```

Comment: `\textsc` takes an argument, so this should be `\textsc{\name}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've copied this part of the code for the original question and it works, because the parameter is only one token `\name` and the macro `\textsc` has one undelimited parameter. If the real parameter is one token then it could be in braces or not. On the other hand, you are right that the usage `\textsc{\name}` is more clear and educational.